# Parse REST API shwoing sent but device doesn't show Push

Tags: python, ios, parse-platform

My iOS app is not receiving Parse notifications sent through Python and the REST API that parse tells us. Parse does say the push is sent and has targeted the test device.

Here is my Python code:

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/1/push', json.dumps({
                                                 "channels": [
                                                              "gen"
                                                              ],
                                                 "data": {
                                                 "alert": "Testing",
                                                 "sound": "shsshort.mp3",
                                                 }
                                                 }), {
                   "X-Parse-Application-Id": "KEY_REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY",
                   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "KEY_REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY",
                   "Content-Type": "application/json"
                   })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

Thank you for your help in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Parse indicates that the push has been sent, then you back end code should be fine.

Most likely you are using wrong provisioning profile when signing the app. That's why it does not receive the push notification.

> Make sure that you are code signing your app with the correct
>   provisioning profile. If you have uploaded a Development Push
>   Notification Certificate to Parse, you will only receive push
>   notifications if you built your app with a Development Provisioning
>   Profile. If you have uploaded a Production Push Notification
>   Certificate, you should sign your app with a Distribution Provisioning
>   Profile. Ad Hoc and App Store Distribution Provisioning Profiles
>   should both work when your app is configured with a Production Push
>   Notification Certificate.

Also double check all the points described in the [Troubleshooting Push Notification](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#troubleshooting/iOS) section of Parse Push documentation.

Comment: Thanks! It was the profile problem, switched parse keys and it worked as expected!